# getFeeData() is not a function

Tags: web3js, gas, ethers.js

i'm always got `getFeeData() is not a function` ?
i was confused read on [etherjs documentation](https://docs.ethers.io/v5/api/providers/provider/#Provider-getFeeData).

[image]

```
const feeData = await this.web3.currentProvider.getFeeData();
```

Answer (score 1):

You're looking at `etherjs` documentation but using `web3` library - it fails because web3 doesn't have that method.

In `web3` you can call `web3.getBlock("latest")` and check `minimumGasPrice` in result for minimum gas required for that block. Calculate your max gas price accordingly.